# Symfony 6.1 - Programatically login user

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to automatically login in a programatical way. (context; I got a seperate account system for admins, if a person is an admin (s)he should be able to login as a user, so I got the userIdentifier)

In symfony 3.3 the way this was done was by;

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main'], $user->getRoles());
$securityContext->setToken($token);
```

In symfony 5.* I did read something about UserAuthenticatorInterface::authenticateUser(UserInterface $user)

However, in Symfony 6 it requires more arguments, one of them being a AuthenticatorInterface and a Request (`public function authenticateUser(UserInterface $user, AuthenticatorInterface $authenticator, Request $request, array $badges = []): ?Response;`). I get that it is used when a user requests authentication with a request that these could be used in this function.

I already tried it by making a UsernamePasswordToken and adding that token to the storage (`TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage`);

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$tokenStorage->setToken($token);
```

But then I got;

```
You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.
```

What is the best way to login an user programatically?